# Openlayers - Interaction Click Handler and DrawEnd

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I'm having some trouble with my `DrawEnd` and `OnClick` event. I've tried changing the condition to `singleClick`, `click`, and have removed it.

- If Condition is added to the interaction, `DrawEnd` is not called (I Need `DrawEnd` to place the point)
- If I remove the condition, the click handler is not called, but `DrawEnd` is.

Since the click is not handled, it seems to go into some sort of Panning mode and the map moves wherever I move my mouse.

My process is this..

- user clicks to add a point and an attribute screen for the point is displayed.
- Once the user enters attributes, the screen goes away and then they can drop a point.
- When the point is placed, a service is called to do stuff
- if service determines its a bad point, It remove is automatically removed from the map.

  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source : addrVectorSource,
  type: "Point",
  //condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick
  });

---

It appears I'm getting an error during the on drawend function:

> ol-debug.js:99465 Uncaught TypeError: this.source_.addFeature is not a function

```
    //[DRAW]
draw.on('drawend', function (e) {
    console.log('drawend');
    start_drawing = false;
    
    //var id = guid();
    if (typeof ($scope.addr.prefix) == 'undefined') {
        $scope.addr.prefix = '';
    }
    if (typeof ($scope.addr.suffix) == 'undefined') {
        $scope.addr.suffix = '';
    }
    var id = $scope.addr.prefix + $scope.addr.addrnbr + $scope.addr.suffix + '-' + $scope.selAddr.uuid; 
    e.feature.featureID = id;
    e.feature.setId(id);
    $scope.map.removeInteraction(draw);
    $scope.map.removeInteraction(modify);
    $scope.map.removeInteraction(select);
    e.feature.setProperties({
        'id': id,
        'name': "Point",  // Can be anything
        'description': 'Some values',
        'addrnum': ($scope.addr.prefix + $scope.addr.addrnbr + $scope.addr.suffix).toUpperCase()
    })
    
    $scope.nLon = e.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
    $scope.nLat = e.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[1];
    $scope.addID = e.feature.getId();

    var lcstat = $scope.addr.lifeCycleStatus;
    var lifecycle = LCSSearch($scope.lifeStatus.lifeCycles, lcstat);

    var featyp = $scope.addr.featureType;
    var featuretype = FTSearch($scope.featTypes.features, featyp);

    addrVectorSource.addFeature(e.feature);

    //ID = addrnum + segmentUUID
    $scope.nAddAddress($scope.nLat, $scope.nLon, $scope.addr.addrnbr, $scope.uuid, $scope.addr.prefix, $scope.addr.suffix, $scope.addr.lifeCycleStatus, $scope.addr.featureType, $scope.sSegment.SNSID, $scope.sSegment.StreetNameFk, id, lifecycle, featuretype);
    });




  //[DRAW]
// Call Service to check placement permissions
// aid = AddrNum + StreetUUID
$scope.nAddAddress = function (lat, lon, addrnum, suuid, prefix, suffix, lcstat, featyp, SNSID, SNFK, aid, lifecycle, featuretype) {
    var UTObj = {
        token: Lockr.get('token'),
        uid: Lockr.get('user'),
    };

    var mapID = $scope.mapid;

    var promise = MapService.AddAddress(UTObj, mapID, suuid, lat, lon, addrnum, prefix, suffix, lcstat, featyp, SNSID, SNFK, aid, lifecycle, featuretype);
    promise.then(
      function (payload) {
          $scope.AddrRet = payload.data.PlacePointResult;
          //Assign AddrRet.aid to drawn feature
          $scope.assignAddressUUID(aid, $scope.AddrRet.UUID);

          $scope.drawing = false;
          console.log($scope.AddrRet.msg);
          var msg = $scope.AddrRet.msg;
          $scope.toastMessage(msg);

          $scope.editState = 'NONE';
          $scope.hbtnD = $scope.hbtnoff;
          console.log('DrawingOff');


      },
      function (errorPayload) {
          console.log('Error Adding Address');
          $scope.removeAddressFeature(aid);

          $scope.drawing = false;
          var msg = errorPayload.data.msg;
          $scope.toastMessage(msg);

          $scope.editState = 'NONE';
          $scope.hbtnD = $scope.hbtnoff;
          console.log('DrawingOff');

      });
};
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to show some more code. Are you using all these tags?

Comment: Jonatas, 
Yes, I'm using Angular and Openlayers .   Thanks.   I've done a bit more research and an error is appearing in the on Drawend function.  Once my point is placed, I attempt to validate it in the DB.  If the user is not allowed to place a point there, it is removed.    I guess the map goes into a weird panning state and waits for me to click again before the point is placed, because of the error that arises.
ol-debug.js:99465 Uncaught TypeError: this.source_.addFeature is not a function